# Загрузить офлайн карты из файла mbtiles и вывести их в react native приложении для Android

Tags: react-native, android-offline, mapbox-android

Мне нужно отобразить офлайн-карту в мобильном приложении для Android на React Native. У меня есть сгенерированный файл mbtiles. Пробовал разные библиотеки.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Какую библиотеку лучше использовать? Если можно дайте, примеры кода или аналогичные реализации.

мой код:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const MapScreen = () => {
  const [mapReady, setMapReady] = useState(false);
  const [offlineMapUri, setOfflineMapUri] = useState(null);

  //change **.****** to youre test data
  const YOUR_INITIAL_LATITUDE = **.******;
  const YOUR_INITIAL_LONGITUDE = **.******;
  const YOUR_INITIAL_LATITUDE_DELTA = *.**;
  const YOUR_INITIAL_LONGITUDE_DELTA = *.**;
  const YOUR_MARKER_LATITUDE = **.******;
  const YOUR_MARKER_LONGITUDE = **.******;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadOfflineMap();
  }, []);

  const loadOfflineMap = async () => {
    
    const offlineMapPath = `${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/Android/data/com.android.slk3/files/my_map.mbtiles`;

    try {
      
      const mapFileExists = await RNFS.exists(offlineMapPath);

      if (mapFileExists) {
        setOfflineMapUri(`file://${offlineMapPath}`);
      } else {
        console.log('file not found.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading map:', error);
    }
  };

  const onMapLayout = () => {
    setMapReady(true);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {mapReady && offlineMapUri ? (
        <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: YOUR_INITIAL_LATITUDE,
            longitude: YOUR_INITIAL_LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: YOUR_INITIAL_LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: YOUR_INITIAL_LONGITUDE_DELTA,
          }}
          onLayout={onMapLayout}
        >
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: YOUR_MARKER_LATITUDE,
              longitude: YOUR_MARKER_LONGITUDE,
            }}
            title="Your Marker"
            description="This is your marker"
          />
        </MapView>
      ) : (
        <View>
          <Text>mapReady: {mapReady}</Text>
          <Text>offlineMapUri: {offlineMapUri}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default MapScreen;
```